# Transclude a page from another language or another project

Tags: wikipedia, mediawiki

In Wikipedia, to copy the content of another page (called "transclusion"), you just need to add `{{:SourcePageName}}` in the destination page.

Is it possible to **transclude** a page from:

- **Another language** ? something like `{{:fr:SamePageInFrench}}`
- **Another sister project** (WikiBooks, WikiVersity) ? something like `{{:wikibooks:PageInWikiBooks}}`

Transclusion documentation: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Transclusion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. As specified in the [documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Transclusion#Transclusion_syntax):

> The general syntax for transclusion on Wikipedia is `{{Namespace:Pagename}}`, where `Namespace:Pagename` describes the title of a Wikipedia page.

The full list of namespaces is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Namespace), but it includes only pages on the English Wikipedia site, so neither in other languages or sister projects.